# c# Odata 8.0 how convert result from applyto to IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, odata

I am using OData and I don't want to use IQueryable on my controller action. Instead, I am sending ODataQueryOptions to my handler, and ApplyTo is working perfectly, returning an IQueryable. However, now I need an IQueryable and I am stuck. When I don't use $select and $expand, everything is okay. But when I do use them, I realize that it's not an IQueryable with customers, but with some wrapper called SelectSome. Is there any way to solve this? Thank you.

Handler

```
    IQueryable<Customer> customers = _customerRepository.GetAll();

    request.Input.Validate(new ODataValidationSettings()
    {
        AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllMathFunctions
    });

    IQueryable data = request.Input.ApplyTo(customers, new ODataQuerySettings()); 

    IQueryable<Customer> dataRdy = data as IQueryable<Customer>; // Not working return null
    IQueryable<Customer> dataRdy2 = data.Cast<Customer>();
    List<Customer> dataList = dataRdy2.ToList(); // Throws an exception below
```

Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectSome`1[Domain.Entities.Customer]' and 'Domain.Entities.Customer'.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateCast(ShapedQueryExpression source, Type resultType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Application.Handlers.TestQueryHandler.Handle(TestQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\user\workspace\WebApiOpenData\Src\Application\Handlers\TestQuery.cs:line 51
   at Mediator.Behaviors.AuthorizationBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApi.Controllers.v1.CustomersController.Get(ODataQueryOptions filter) in C:\user\workspace\WebApiOpenData\Src\WebApi\Controllers\v1\CustomersController.cs:line 36
   at lambda_method7(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Looks like exception is create a log entry in  Swagger (probably Log4net) with error message. See if you can check the log file for more info.

Comment: @jdweng it's not about swagger

Comment: I didn't say it was about swagger,  Just that log file is being generated.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options?force_isolation=true

Comment: But i know where is problem

Comment: You probably are not enabling the OData query options.

Comment: The link you sent is for .Net Framework I need for .NET Core and what I am writing here is at the very end.

Comment: Core should be very similar to Net (if not the same).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue in the library unfortunately exists, you can find an issue about it on Github. It can be done either manually, you can find it in one of the issues on Github. Or if you are using AutoMapper, there is an extension that is very easy to use - AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData

I hope it will help.